# Issues with AWS S3 bucket and DigitalOcean deployment

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, digital-ocean, aws-code-deploy

I’m trying to implement AWS S3 bucket in typescript via:

```
import { S3Client } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

// Load environment variables from .env file
dotenv.config();

// Check if AWS credentials are provided in the environment
if (!process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME || !process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY || !process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY || !process.env.AWS_BUCKET_REGION) {
  throw new Error('One or more AWS environment variables are not defined.');
};

// Create an S3 client instance
const s3Client = new S3Client({
  region: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_REGION,
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY,
  }
});

// Function to get the bucket name
function getBucketName(): string {
    return process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME || "";
};

// Export the S3 client instance and the getBucketName function
export { s3Client as s3, getBucketName };
```

```
import { getBucketName, s3 } from '../utils/awsImport';
import { PutObjectCommand, PutObjectCommandInput } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';

async function uploadURIToS3(imageContent: Buffer, fileName: string) {
  try {
    const params: PutObjectCommandInput = {
      Bucket: getBucketName(),
      Key: fileName,
      Body: imageContent,
      ContentType: 'image/jpeg'
    };
  
    const command = new PutObjectCommand(params);
    const result = await s3.send(command);
    console.log('Upload successful:', result);
    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error uploading to S3:', error);
    throw error;
  }
};

export { uploadURIToS3 };
```

```
import { getBucketName, s3 } from '../utils/awsImport';
import { GetObjectCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';
import { getSignedUrl } from '@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner';

// Function to retrieve the URL of an S3 object
async function downloadURLFromS3(objectKey: string): Promise<string> {
    const params = {
      Bucket: getBucketName(),
      Key: objectKey,
    };
    
    try {
      const signedUrl = await getSignedUrl(s3, new GetObjectCommand(params), { expiresIn: 300 });
      const urlParts = new URL(signedUrl); // Split the signed URL into its components
      const shorterUrl = `${urlParts.origin}${urlParts.pathname}`; // Compose a shorter version of the URL with minimal query parameters
      console.log('Download sucessful:', shorterUrl);
      return shorterUrl
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error generating signed URL:', error);
      throw error;
    }
  };
  
export { downloadURLFromS3 };
```

I wanted to store image URI into my S3 bucket and download the URL of the images in the bucket and I ran into this issue when trying to deploy my code on digitalocean:

```
[2023-08-27 23:47:29] FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory [2023-08-27 23:47:29] 1: 0xb090e0 node::Abort() [node] [2023-08-27 23:47:29] 2: 0xa1b70e [node] [2023-08-27 23:47:29] 3: 0xce1a20 v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node] [2023-08-27 23:47:29] 4: 0xce1dc7 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node] [2023-08-27 23:47:29] 5: 0xe99435 [node] [2023-08-27 23:47:29] 6: 0xe99f16 [node] [2023-08-27 23:47:29] 7: 0xea843e [node] [2023-08-27 23:47:29] 8: 0xea8e80 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node] [2023-08-27 23:47:29] 9: 0xeabdfe v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node] [2023-08-27 23:47:29] 10: 0xe6d33a v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin) [node] [2023-08-27 23:47:29] 11: 0x11e61e6 v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInYoungGeneration(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node] [2023-08-27 23:47:29] 12: 0x15d9e59 [node] [2023-08-27 23:47:29] Aborted [2023-08-27 23:47:29] [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file change
```

Can someone give me a hand? I tried to increase the Node.js memory limit in the configuration with node --max-old-space-size=4096, and 8192 and it’s still not working.

I also tried to deploy using Amazon EC2 and it's failing too.

It runs and works fine on my localhost, and builds on DigitalOcean. But once it gets to the deploying stage, it yields the error listed above.